# Are there Lasers in wavelenght of UHF or radio frequency?

Tags: laser, radio-frequency

how exists lasers in many wavelength in electromagnetic spectrum, like UV, VIS and IR. I don't know nothing about others wavelength as X-ray or radio frequency.

Comment: Are you thinking about a [maser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maser)?